# How to embed Autodesk Forge Viewer with mobile app?

Tags: ios, angular, ionic-framework, autodesk-forge, autodesk

I was using ionic and angular to develop a mobile app that could display the pdf, image or dwg file within the forge viewer. It works all perfectly on the website monitor, but when I deploy the app in the ios phone and the android phone, I found out that if I open the dwg file and some image file, the app will crash sometimes. Btw, some extension is not supported by ios, such as pushpin extension. It seems that three js works not good in ios.

I also check the document about the "Create iPhone Apps Using Forge Viewer & React Native" in the forge viewer official website. After I follow the steps to build the app with native react and deploy it on my phone, pdf and image file works good but not for the dwg file.

I have experience building apps with ionic but not React Native. Compare to these two frameworks, which one should I pick? If I continue using the ionic framework if there is any way I could use to improve the performance of the forge viewer inside my app? or would it be better to switch to React Native?

For tech questions, how could I avoid the app crash and improve the performance? I checked the A360 app on the app store, I found out that the app is using the offline data, it will download all the data once it opens the file. Should I do the same way?
[App Viewer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yjtAX.png)

Comment: It is okay to open the dwg file less than 1mb very soon, but if the file is larger than 1mb, it will take some time to load and is hard to zoom the viewer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically both RN and Ionic embeds Viewer as external dependencies in WebView so there's no material difference/pros and cons in the approach to embed.

As such I'd recommend to go with the framework you are more comfortable/experienced with - although RN seems to be blessed with a couple of samples but those do little more than scratch the surface when it comes to a real world solution so you can get up to speed with their approach and go from there.

Performance wise yes - downloading the derivatives (SVFs) to the client side would certainly improve load times - you can either see [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/forge-svf-extractor-nodejs) and [here](https://github.com/cyrillef/extract.autodesk.io) to download, store/package locally and [override request handling of WebView](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/offline-viewing-android) to load them (as Viewer only supports http(s) and not file or other protocols) , or cache the resources with Service Worker following [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/disconnected-workflows) and [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/native-experience-viewer-build-viewers-offline-workflows-progessive-web-apps).

You can look around SO for other performance related questions - mostly they are about setting the memory options, correct FPS targets, consolidating geometry, selective loading and adjusting navigation options - for specific issues you can post another question or email forge.help at autodesk.com for assistance.

> It is okay to open the dwg file less than 1mb very soon, but if the file is larger than 1mb, it will take some time to load and is hard to zoom the viewer.

I'd suggest to download or cache the derivatives (SVF) locally to boost loading performance. I was unable to reproduce any difficulty with zooming - did you set viewport in head meta tag?

Comment: no, I didn't set the viewer inside the head tag. Maybe the resource is still loading, so I can't operate on it. I could first try to cache or download them. Thanks, help much.